# Consuming POST method of WCF REST service in Javascript or XmlHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, wcf, rest

I am trying to access a WCF REST service with GET Method. The problem with this is, my parameter at times   could be very long (more characters greater than maximum characters of URL String), So I am thinking to implement the same functionality with POST.

Note: I am consuming the service through JavaScript (I don't want to use JQuery - Since I am already using using Sencha (Sencha doesn't provide any POST method)) XmlHttpRequest.

```
function GetData() {
   // alert("hello");
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "http://lclhost.com/WcfWebService.svc/doworks";
   // alert("hello1");
    xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
   /// alert("hello2");
    var params = "name=Jack";
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () { //Call a function when the state changes.
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
        else {
            alert("Status:"+xmlhttp.status+"State"+xmlhttp.readyState);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.onerror = function (e) {
        //alert error
        alert('error');
    }
xmlhttp.send(params);
}
```

and my service is

```
[OperationContract]
 [WebInvoke(Method="POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "doworks")]
 string DoWorks(string name);
```

While consuming the javascript function through asp.Net web application, I am getting an alert of Status:0State4. I am not sure what is the problem. Can you guys help me how to consume this Service in POST through XMLHttpRequest/Javascript?

Comment: did u try to use url like this url= 'http://' + document.domain + '/WcfWebService.svc/doworks',

Comment: I published my service in localhost and my url is http://localhost/WcfWebService.svc/doworks